# Why is my Twitter bot not authenticating while creating bot?

Tags: twitter, developer-tools

why I am always getting authentication error while creating bot for twitter. Though I am using correct keys. Below is the code:-

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("XXXX", "XXX")
auth.set_access_token("C-HmO3PQt0Z1X44FY9v9jmk53rL7x5xB", "VCCCC")
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True)

try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("Authentication Successful")
except:
    print("Authentication Error")
```

Comment: What level of API access do you have (Essential or Elevated)? The verify_credentials function is a legacy v1.1 feature and you will need Elevated access to use it - it is not strictly necessary and you may be able to use v2 for your purposes, Tweepy supports it.

Comment: @AndyPiper I have Essential for now it's in pending state for Elevated

Comment: Again, you likely do not need the verify_credentials call. I'd suggest trying to solve your coding problem using v2 - v1.1 will go away in the future.